# Non Serializable object in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Apache Flink to perform analytics on streaming data.

I am using a **dependency whose object takes more than 10 secs to create** as it is reads several files present in hdfs before initialisation.

***If I initialise the object in open method I get a timeout Exception and if in the constructor of a sink/flatmap, I get serialisation exception.***

**Currently I am using static block** to initialise the object in some other class, using Preconditions.checkNotNull(MGenerator.mGenerator) in main file and then it's working if used in a flatmap of sink.

**Is there a way to create a non serializable dependency's object which might take more than 10 secs to be initialised in Flink's flatmap or sink?**

```
public class DependencyWrap {

  static MGenerator mGenerator;

  static {
    final String configStr = "{}";
    final Config config = new Gson().fromJson(config, Config.class);
    mGenerator = new MGenerator(config);
  }

}
```

```
public class MyStreaming {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Preconditions.checkNotNull(MGenerator.mGenerator);
    final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setParallelism(parallelism);
    ...
    input.flatMap(new RichFlatMapFunction<Map<String,Object>,List<String>>() {

      @Override
      public void open(Configuration parameters) {
      }

      @Override
      public void flatMap(Map<String,Object> value, Collector<List<String>> out) throws Exception {

        out.collect(MFVGenerator.mfvGenerator.generateMyResult(value.f0, value.f1));
      }

    });

  }
}
```

Also, Please correct me if I am wrong about the question.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the exception? I'd run into a similar problem (long delay in `open()` caused timeout) and the stack trace helped me figure out which Flink config value to increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `open` is usually the right place to load external lookup sources. The timeout is a bit odd, maybe there is a configuration around it.

However, if it's huge using a static loader (either static class as you did or singleton) has the benefit that you only need to load it once for all parallel instances of the task on the same task manager. Hence, you save memory and CPU time. This is especially true for you, as you use the same data structure in two separate tasks. Further, the static loader can be lazily initialized when it's used for the first time to avoid the timeout in `open`.

The clear downside of this approach is that the testability of your code suffers. There are some ways around that, which I could expand if there is interest.

I don't see a benefit of using the proxy serializer pattern. It's unnecessarily complex (custom serialization in Java) and offers little benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Doing it in the Open method is 100% the right way to do it. Is Flink giving you a timeout exception, or the object?

As a last ditch method, you could wrap your object in a class that contains both the object and it's JSON string or Config (is Config serializable?) with the object marked transient and then override the ReadObject/WriteObject methods to call the constructor. If the mGenerator object itself is stateless (and you'll have other problems if it's not), the serialization code should get called only once when jobs are distributed to taskmanagers.